# How can I write multiple lines in expect program for the spawn command?

Tags: bash, expect, scp

I have written this little script for getting multiple files from my remote server to my host computer:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp \
user@remote:/home/user/{A.txt,B.txt} \
/home/user_local/Documents
expect "password: "
send "somesecretpwd\r"
interact
```

This is working fine, but when I want to make new lines between the files like this:

```
user@remote:/home/user/{A.txt,\
B.txt} \
```

I am getting the following error(s):

```
scp: /home/user/{A.txt,: No such file or directory
scp: B.txt}: No such file or directory
```

I tried this:

```
user@remote:"/home/user/{A.txt,\
B.txt}" \
```

getting:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
cp: cannot stat 'B.txt}"': No such file or directory
```

or this:

```
"user@remote:/home/user/{A.txt,\
B.txt}" \
```

getting the same error at the beginning.

How can I write the files in multiple lines but so that the program is working correctly? I need this for a better readability of the choosen files.

Edit:
Only changed the local user name to user_local

Comment: I suggest to use `sshpass`.

Comment: My problem with `sshpass` is that I must pass complicated arguments for multihop (I must use ssh twice at least in a row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who want to solve a similar problem with only using expect:

You can write a list of files and then concat all files to one string.

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

set files {\ # a list of files
A.txt\
B.txt\
C.txt\
}

# will return the concatenated string with all files
# in this example it would be: A.txt,B.txt,C.txt
set concat [join $files ,]

# self made version of concat
# set concat [lindex $files 0] # get the first file
# set last_idx [expr {[llength $files]-1}] # calc the last index from the list
# set rest_files [lrange $files 1 $last_idx] # get other files
# foreach file $rest_files {
#     set concat $concat,$file # append the concat varibale with a comma and the other file
# }
# # puts "$concat" # only for testing the output

spawn scp \
user@remote:/home/doublepmcl/{$concat} \
/home/user_local/Documents
expect "password: "
send "somesecretpwd\r"
interact
```

Comment: You can simplify the middle section to just: `set concat [join $files ,]` - see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm .  Also the backslashes between the entries in your "files" list are redundant since any white space including newlines can be used to separate list elements.

Comment: Thank you for the shorter code, I will add this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl (and so Expect) [`\<NEWLINE><SPACEs>`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) will be converted into one single `<SPACE>` so you cannot write a string containing no spaces into multiple lines.

```
% puts "abc\
        def"
abc def
% puts {abc\
        def}
abc def
%
```

Comment: Ah nice explanation. To send only some specific files with a expect script with a readable code I could write another script (e.g. in python) which creates the needed expect script.
Also does e.g. "\n\n<space>" results in "<space>"?

Comment: The *spaces* as in `\<NEWLINE><SPACEs>` only include `<space>s` (0x20) and `<tab>s` (0x09).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the filenames are really longer (not much point otherwise) you could use a couple of variables like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f

set A A.txt
set B B.txt

spawn scp \
user@remote:/home/user/{$A,$B} \
/home/user/Documents
expect "password: "
send "somesecretpwd"
interact
```

Comment: For couple of files this could be used as a temporary solution.